# Count occurrences of factor in R, with zero counts reported

Tags: r, plyr

I want to count the number of occurrences of a factor in a data frame. For example, to count the number of events of a given type in the code below:

```
library(plyr)
events <- data.frame(type = c('A', 'A', 'B'),
                       quantity = c(1, 2, 1))
ddply(events, .(type), summarise, quantity = sum(quantity))
```

The output is the following:

```
     type quantity
1    A        3
2    B        1
```

However, what if I know that there are three types of events `A`, `B` and `C`, and I also want to see the count for `C` which is `0`? In other words, I want the output to be:

```
     type quantity
1    A        3
2    B        1
3    C        0
```

How do I do this? It feels like there should be a function defined to do this somewhere.

The following are my two not-so-good ideas about how to go about this.

**Idea #1:** I know I could do this by using a `for` loop, but I know that it is widely said that if you are using a `for` loop in `R`, then you are doing something wrong, there must be a better way to do it.

**Idea #2:** Add dummy entries to the original data frame. This solution works but it feels like there should be a more elegant solution.

```
events <- data.frame(type = c('A', 'A', 'B'),
                       quantity = c(1, 2, 1))
events <- rbind(events, data.frame(type = 'C', quantity = 0))
ddply(events, .(type), summarise, quantity = sum(quantity))
```

Comment: `e <- sapply(events, FUN=as.factor); table(e)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You get this for free if you define your `events` variable correctly as a factor with the desired three levels:

```
R> events <- data.frame(type = factor(c('A', 'A', 'B'), c('A','B','C')), 
+                       quantity = c(1, 2, 1))
R> events
  type quantity
1    A        1
2    A        2
3    B        1
R> table(events$type)

A B C 
2 1 0 
R>
```

Simply calling `table()` on the factor already does the right thing, and `ddply()` can too 
if you tell it not to `drop`:

```
R> ddply(events, .(type), summarise, quantity = sum(quantity), .drop=FALSE)
  type quantity
1    A        3
2    B        1
3    C        0
R>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> xtabs(quantity~type, events)
type
A B C 
3 1 0
```

Comment: Doh, even better. Nice. Somehow I always forget about `xtabs`.  But also needs the corrected factor variable I show.

Comment: I only used the OP's data. There is an implicit `sum` in `xtabs`.

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr library

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(level = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
                   value = c(1:6))

data %>%
  group_by(level) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  View
```

If you choose also to perform mean, min, max operations, try this

```
data %>%
  group_by(level) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), Max_val = max(value), Min_val = min(value)) %>%
  View
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar to @DWin's answer:

```
> aggregate(quantity~type, events, FUN=sum)
  type quantity
1    A        3
2    B        1
3    C        0
```

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Or his definition, with the dummy entries (what I actually used).

Comment: Which amounts to the same in a more convoluted way -- the char variable gets turned into a factor later by aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

In data you put your dataframe and into levels your categories.

```
table(factor(data, levels = 1:5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn `type` column to factor and use `count`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

events %>% count(type = factor(type, c('A', 'B', 'C')), .drop = FALSE)

#  type n
#1    A 2
#2    B 1
#3    C 0
```

Another option is `complete`.

```
events %>%
  count(type) %>%
  complete(type = c('A', 'B', 'C'), fill = list(n = 0))
```